# Installing graph-tool with macports

Tags: installation, python, macports

I'm trying to install graph-tool for Python using MacPorts, but for some reason it is not installing. I checked the port log and found many errors like this:

```
:info:build ./../fast_vector_property_map.hh:136:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy c\
onstructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
:info:build class unchecked_vector_property_map
:info:build       ^
:info:build fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
:info:build 20 errors generated.
```

and this:

```
:info:build In file included from graph_eigenvector.cc:24:
:info:build ./graph_eigenvector.hh:44:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'boos\
t::unchecked_vector_property_map<double, boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, unsig\
ned long>>'
:info:build         CentralityMap c_temp(vertex_index, num_vertices(g));
:info:build                       ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and finally

```
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port py27-graph-tool returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 22204 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
    invoked from within
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: targets not executed for py27-graph-tool: org.macports.activate org.macports.bu\
ild org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
```

I don't really get what is going on. I also tried to install graph-tool manually but couldn't get all of the dependencies (specifically, pycairo) to work. What could be going on? Could MacPorts have misinstalled some dependent